# Foreman: ERF42-9666 [Foreman::Exception]: HTTP boot requires proxy with httpboot feature and http_port exposed setting

Tags: foreman

I would like to provision hosts with foreman.

**Problem:** 
I use discovery for new hosts. The hosts gets discovered. I can configure it. When I click on submit, I get:
ERF42-9666 [Foreman::Exception]: HTTP boot requires proxy with httpboot feature and http_port exposed setting

**Expected outcome:**
The new host is rebootet and installed.

**Foreman and Proxy versions:**
Foreman: 2.0.0

**Foreman and Proxy plugin versions:**
foreman_discovery: 16.0.1
foreman_remote_execution: 3.0.3
foreman-tasks: 1.1.0
foreman_ansible: 5.0.1

**Distribution and version:**
Debian 10.3

**Other relevant data:**
I used 
    `foreman-installer --full-help`
to print my current settings and uploaded them to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/j79Zs2b7
I hope this helps, if you prefer to have them here in the board, please tell me.

When I got the error the first time I found: https://community.theforeman.org/t/cannot-create-host-erf42-9666-with-foreman-1-24rc2/16219
But running 
    `foreman-installer --foreman-proxy-httpboot true`
did not fix it, though it was false before. The setting `--foreman-proxy-httpboot-listen-on` is "both" by default.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to enable http proxy:

```
--foreman-proxy-http true
```